# How to exec the cli code of python through k8s's dns address

Tags: python, kubernetes

If there is a test k8s pod like below, how to execute the test.py through k8s dns address?

```
# dockerfile.test -- have a test.py under /test fold.
FROM base image
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
COPY . /test
WORKDIR /test
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# test.yaml -- have a dns name http://test-api.test-system.svc.cluster.local:8080
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: test-system
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-api
  namespace: test-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: test
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: test-api
    port: 8080
    targetPort: test-api
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
      containers:
      - name: test-api
        image: test-image
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to expose container's port, and service targetPort must match conatiner's port name or port number.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
      containers:
      - name: test-api
        image: test-image
        ports:
        - name: test-api
          containerPort: 8080
```